# SVG automatic morph animation between 2 frames

Tags: animation, svg

I have 2 SVG images of the same objects having the different configuratrions (translations and rotations). The simplified example:

fil1.svg:

```
  <svg width="800" height="800">
    <rect id="r1" fill="#11CC99" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="200" 
    transform="matrix(0.8211913,-0.570653,0.570653,0.8211913,0,100)"
    />
    <circle id="c1"  fill="#99CC11"  cx="0" cy="0" r="100" 
      transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,242,100)"
    />
  </svg>
```

file2.svg:

```
  <svg width="800" height="800">
    <rect id="r1" fill="#11CC99" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="200" 
      transform="matrix(0.8211913,-0.570653,0.570653,0.8211913,30,80)"
    />
    <circle id="c1" fill="#99CC11" cx="0" cy="0" r="100"
      transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,240,300)"
    />
  </svg>
```

Is there a tool (or library for Python, JS...) which automatically build third svg file with animation starting from first configuration to second? I expect that the resulting svg file contains the script like:

```
<svg>
...
    <circle id="c1" fill="#99CC11"  cx="0" cy="0" r="100" 
      transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,242,100)">
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML"
        type="translate"
        from="242 100"
        to="240 300"
        begins="0s"
        dur="1s"/>
    </circle>
</svg>
```

And the similar code for the rect. I expect that coordinates transformation matrices are linear with respect to animation time.

Answer (score 0):

How about 9VAe. See [Six steps to make SVG Animation from Openclipart](http://codepen.io/danjiro/blog/six-steps-to-make-svg-animation-from-clip-art).

1. Open file1.svg with 9VAe.
2. Copy first page to the second page.
3. Import file2.svg to the second page.
4. Modify file1.svg to file2.svg on the second page.
5. Delete file2.svg.
6. Export SVG.

The output SVG is as follows. (I added repeatCount to show transforming.)

```html
<svg width="800" height="800">
  <path fill="#11cc99" stroke="none">
    <animate repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.00s" dur="1.00s"  attributeName="d"
      from="M0.00,100.00L82.06,42.88 196.19,207.12 114.12,264.19 
0.00,100.00 Z"
      to="M31.00,78.06L113.06,20.94 227.19,185.19 145.12,242.25 31.00,78.06 Z" />
  </path>
  <path fill="#99cc11" stroke="none">
    <animate repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.00s" dur="1.00s"  attributeName="d"
      from="M342.00,100.00C342.81,128.19 333.25,151.31 312.69,170.69 C293.31,191.25 270.19,200.81 242.00,200.00 C213.75,200.81 190.56,191.25 171.25,170.69 C150.69,151.31 141.12,128.19 142.00,100.00 C141.12,71.75 150.69,48.56 171.25,29.25 C190.56,8.69 213.75,-0.88 242.00,0.00 C270.19,-0.88 293.31,8.69 312.69,29.25 C333.25,48.56 342.81,71.75 342.00,100.00 Z"
      to="M342.00,299.44C342.81,327.62 333.25,350.75 312.69,370.12 C293.31,390.69 270.19,400.25 242.00,399.44 C213.75,400.25 190.56,390.69 171.25,370.12 C150.69,350.75 141.12,327.62 142.00,299.44 C141.12,271.19 150.69,248.00 171.25,228.69 C190.56,208.12 213.75,198.56 242.00,199.44 C270.19,198.56 293.31,208.12 312.69,228.69 C333.25,248.00 342.81,271.19 342.00,299.44 Z" />

  </path>
</svg>
```